# Can I delete the installation folder of an .tar.gz archive?

Tags: software-installation, directory, software-sources

I installed a software from the sources that I download and compiled myself. 
So I did the following:

```
tar xzfv ~/download/software.tar.gz
cd ~/download/software && ./configure && make
sudo make install
```

**Question:** can I now remove the `~/download/software` folder that I no longer need?
(In other words: where does the software have been installed? Cleverly in the `/bin`, `/opt` etc. folders? Or does the files have been installed in `~/download/software`?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you have run:

```
sudo make install
```

the necessary files are copied in relevant places in the system directories. It may put things in `/usr/local`, may be in `/opt`, may be got distributed throughout other relevant directories in the system. I have come across no package that keeps and runs from that directory. There should be a `README` (or similar) file that should give a clear view of what will be done.

So you can remove the source directory safely, but there could be a `uninstall` file that does exact opposite of `install` i.e. it will remove all files copied so check if you have that. If present, better keep that.

As we are at it, you should use `checkinstall` instead of `make install` as `checkinstall` makes a `.deb` file out of the relevant files to be copied and you can manage it afterwards just by using any package manager e.g. `apt-get`, `aptitude` or from lower level by using `dpkg`. You can install `checkinstall` by:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Then check `man checkinstall`.

Comment: If space is at a premium, a make clean - not make distclean ! - could do away with redundant copies of installation files while keeping source and configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Well that would depend on the package normally I would say you were okay to delete it.

It depends on where the software installed the required files.

In my experience its always been fine. Post more package information for more info!

If you want to test what will happen, stop the running program, deamon etc, then move the installation folder and restart the program! No change in expected behavior? Your safe to remove it! If not kill the program, move the folder back and restart!

Comment: My question is for a general purpose: my `~/download/` folder is full of installation folders... And I didn't knew if the core these software were actually in these folders (so I must not delete them), of if there were a bit like `.deb` or `.exe` files, that are no longer needed once the software installed.

Comment: See my edit, im sure if you just remove them then you will be fine, but if they are critical then be safe and move them first & then delete if they cause no issue